# How to extract diffs and who edited a file via Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way that I can programmatically get diffs of a file that is on Google Drive and information of who modified the file.

It seems that Google Drive API does not provide diffs, but they provide revisions of a file via Revisions API.
Revisions.list() method returns an URL of each revision of a file. So, it is possible to check the difference between two revisions if I download them and compare with each other.
But I cannot know who modified the file in this way. Response of Revisions.list() method returns only one editor of the file if other people are editing at the same time.

Does anyone have any idea how to get such data?
I found that I could see how & who modified a file on Google Drive. 
( File -> See reision history )

Thanks

Comment: What effort did you make?

Comment: also crarify if this is for any drive file or just for a google doc (which has a hidden way to do this)

Comment: I read reference of Google Drive API, and googled if I could do that, but I only found that Drive API doesn't provide diffs.

Comment: Target file is google doc file and MS word document file.